# sql connection errors - prevent me from 'SELECT' data from mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

i'm trying 12 hours now to SELECT data from my DB but i can't.

INSERT works fine. just SELECT not working.

When i run connect() function i'm get lot of errors:

```
      public void connect() {
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://*****.heliohost.org:3306/*****";
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,"*****","****");
            return;//the debugger never succeed to reach this line

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
      }
```

the errors i get from the above connect() function:

```
12-23 16:22:54.460: W/dalvikvm(7473): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Reference;)
12-23 16:22:54.470: I/dalvikvm(7473): Could not find method javax.naming.Reference.get, referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.initializeFrom
12-23 16:22:54.470: W/dalvikvm(7473): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14440: Ljavax/naming/Reference;.get (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/naming/RefAddr;
12-23 16:22:54.470: D/dalvikvm(7473): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
12-23 16:22:54.491: W/dalvikvm(7473): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Reference;)
12-23 16:22:54.491: E/dalvikvm(7473): Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo
12-23 16:22:54.491: W/dalvikvm(7473): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1365 (Ljavax/naming/StringRefAddr;) in Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty;
12-23 16:22:54.491: D/dalvikvm(7473): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0006
```

The next function is falling only when it get to line: "String tem = result.getString("name")":

```
public List<String> selectCategories()
{
    List<String> listCS = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
           Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
           statement.execute("select name from categories");
            ResultSet result=statement.getResultSet();

            if(result!=null)
            {
                while(result.next());
                {   
                    String tem = result.getString("name");
                    listCS.add(tem);                                    

                }//end of while
            }//end of if

    }//end of try
    catch(java.sql.SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listCS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors from the first function suggest that you're using a JNDI named resource to get the connection, not one from DriverManager.

Are you sure that the device can see that host and port?  Does the device have permission to connect?  What does the GRANT in the MySQL database look like?

Your method to get name from categories table isn't good, either.  You don't close any resources in finally blocks.  You should.

Those `// end of while` and `// end of if` comments are heinous.  They don't add information, only clutter.  Expunge those from your code.

Comment: I did 'GRANT ALL' to my user i'm connecting with to the DB. i will add close to resources. but this is not solving my errors.

Comment: Those stack traces aren't what you'd see from a DriverManager connection.  Can you test that class in isolation without Android?  I'd recommend that you do so.

Comment: I did what you said - i create new project and its working perfectly. do you know how can i solve this? /:

Comment: "Working perfectly" sounds like you don't have anything to solve.  What am I missing?

Comment: i want this to work in my android app not just as a normal java app

Comment: I understand that, but if it won't work as a Java app it won't work with Android.  Get one working properly and build off it.